# xamarin Flyoutpage change text color

Tags: xamarin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXjEK.png)

Hello friend

How can I change the color of the text in the title in the picture I am using flyoutpage

How can I change the color of the text in the title in the picture I am using flyoutpage

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the text color of tabs of `TabbedPage` in your screenshot?

If yes, then in android, you can try to create a `Tabbar.xml` in folder `layout` and adding following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"

    app:tabTextColor="@color/your_unselected_text_color"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/your_selected_text_color"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/your_indicator_color"
     />
```

Then inflate this layout with code:

```
 FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
```

The whole code of `MainActivity.cs`

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity 
    {  
       
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
            {
            FormsAppCompatActivity.TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;

            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

            LoadApplication (new App ());
            }
      }
```

On IOS, you can use custom renderer to achieve this.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(TabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            TabBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
            TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Black;
            TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Aydogan İLHAN, I have not heard from you for a couple of days. Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.